# How to splite a string in golang and find out the value at the zero index?

Tags: go

**How to find zero index value from the given string.**

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    var data string

    data = "hello_world_to_goalng"

}
```

Comment: I'm struggling a bit at understanding what your expected result is...?

Comment: Your question is incomplete, but splitting a string in Go is trivial. What have you tried? If one of the many linked duplicates doesn't help, and a search doesn't help, please clarify your question, or ask a new one.